# problem with the width of the photo border on one side

Tags: html, css, sass

I would like to frame the picture in this way, but I do not know what is wrong with the code, that the bottom part of the border is thicker than the top (red border) link to the view
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/quFZn.jpg

Code:

```
  .image {
        flex: 1 1 40rem;
        position: relative;

        &::before,
        &::after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            z-index: -1;
            background: $red;
            height: 25rem;
            width: 25rem;
        }

        &::before {
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        &::after {
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
        }

        img {
            width: 100%;
            padding: .5rem;
        }
    }
```

Comment: position: relative to parent, position absolute to child with negative top and left, the other with negative bottom and right

Answer (score 0):

the idea here is two create two divs and put the them behind the image (responsively using position)

just change the `--outside-value` var for creating bigger border or smaller

with the var in * selector is equal in all two borders :)

hope this helps, good coding!

## here the code

```css
* {
  --outside-value: -0.2em;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body,
#content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#content {
  position: relative;
}

#content img {
  width: 50vw;
  z-index: 1;
}

.border {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 10vh;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}

.border-bottom {
  top: var(--outside-value);
  left: var(--outside-value);
}

.border-top {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: var(--outside-value);
  right: var(--outside-value);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="border border-top"></div>

    <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg">

    <div class="border border-bottom"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```